# How to use k150 pic programmer on Linux?

Tags: pic, usb, linux

I'm trying to start with PIC microcontrollers. I bought this programmer: http://www.kitsrus.com/pdf/k150v2.pdf and a 16F628A.

But I'm not able to use it with my Arch Linux...
How can I do that?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no Linux software for that programmer, however you might be able to get the Windows version working through [Wine](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wine). You will also need a virtual com port driver for the [FTDI USB chip](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm) (this should already be included in your Arch Linux kernel).

If the Windows app refuses to work then the only other option may be to develop your own version. The programmer's software protocol is documented [here](http://www.kitsrus.com/zip/softprotocol5.zip).

Comment: Thx! The wine is not working... Do you have a documentation/tutorial/example on how to write a programmer interface?

Comment: usbpicprog (http://usbpicprog.org/) is a free open source pic programmer. You just need to replace the USB commands with the equivalent serial port commands for your programmer.

Answer (score 4):

To use on linux, you need a python program called **picpro.py**. 
The 2 posts explain:

1. https://eliasandrade.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/como-usar-o-gravador-pic-k150-no-linux/
2. http://www.picbasic.co.uk/forum/showthread.php?t=17429

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please summarize the information at the provided links in case they no longer work in the future.