# K150 PIC Programmer on linux with usbpicprog?

Tags: linux

I'm to search a low cost PIC programmer to use with Debian Linux.
On another [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/128868/how-to-use-k150-pic-programmer-on-linux) i see a comment about use the usbpicprog programs to write .hex files.

With the usbpicprog.org softwares, you can write the .hex trought K150 on 16F628A in Debian/Linux?

On the usbpicprog, they talk about use the PCB used in herself project only!

The PIC programmer is:
http://mlb-s2-p.mlstatic.com/gravador-picburner-k150-usb-pic-de-brindesoftwares-cabos-14980-MLB20093350708_052014-O.jpg

Comment: Any reason you can't use the Microchip supported PICKit 3?

Comment: Cost - K150 is 50% less that PICKit 3. The idea is buy 40 programmers!

Comment: You're paying for reliability. I know nothing about the K150, but clones and 3rd-party programmers tend to suffer from similar problems. They may not work on all (or even most) device families, you may have limited (or no) support, and often the product goes dead after the original developer decides to move on to other things.

Comment: K150 is originally from Kits 'R us (www.kitsrus.com/pic.html) and has been around for, I think, more than 15 years.  It is well supported because of Asian clone manufacturers.  Although I don't use that product any more, I'm pretty sure that the software that runs it is updated on an irregular basis to handle more modern chips.

Answer (score 2):

The software from usbpricprog is build for your own programmer.
To use K150 programmer you need a python program called **picpro.py**, the 2 posts explain:

1. https://eliasandrade.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/como-usar-o-gravador-pic-k150-no-linux/
2. http://www.picbasic.co.uk/forum/showthread.php?t=17429

Thanks